# Superconductor surface resistance

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity, classical-electrodynamics, dissipation

If the superconductive state is due to a phase transition from ohmic to a state a zero-resistivity, why the superconductive materials are usually identified by their surface resistance, or by their RRR parameter?

Comment: For superconductors usually you use the resistivity right above the transition, or extrapolate the resistivity to zero temperature.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of evaluation the surface resistance of a superconductor thin, is very important in the Superconductive Resonant Cavity in microwave band.

The response of a superconductor to RF fields as well described by the **Two-Fluid Model** that consist to identify the

- Cooper pairs as superfluid
- Unpaired electrons as normal fluid, yield conductivity $\sigma_n$.

Studying the response of two fluids to a periodic electric field we can separate the two different contributes:

- Normal Current by Ohm's Law $J_n=\sigma_nE_0\exp(-i\omega t)$
- Supercurrent given by London equations $J_s=i\frac{n_c 2 e^2}{m_e \omega}E_0 \exp(-i\omega t)$

Now we can write the total current as

$J=J_n+J_s = \sigma E_0 \exp(-i\omega t)$

with $\sigma$ is a complex conductivity given by

$\sigma = \sigma_n + i\sigma_s \text{ with } \sigma_s=\frac{2n_ce^2}{m_e\omega}=\frac{1}{\mu_0\lambda_L^2\omega}$

So, is possible to define the ***surface resistance*** as: *the real part of the the complex surface impedance*

$R_{surf} = \Re\left(\frac{1}{\lambda_L(\sigma_n+i\sigma_s)}\right)=\frac{1}{\lambda_L}\frac{\sigma_n}{\sigma_n^2+\sigma_s^2}$

at microwave frequency $\sigma_n^2 \ll \sigma_s^2 $ so $\boxed{R_{surf}\approx\frac{\sigma_n}{\lambda_L\sigma_s^2}}$

This model can be refined using an order parameter strictly link to the impurities of material.

Reference:

[1] - *Basic Principles of RF Superconductivity and Superconducting
Cavities* - Peter Schmuser

[2] - *Surface Resistance of a Superconductor* - H. Safa

Answer (score 0):

Superconductors possess zero resistance when cooled **below critical temperature**. There is a threshold between zero resistance and close-to-zero resistance.

I'm sending you links to two very useful links, you might want to check them out. Read [this](http://www.supraconductivite.fr/en/index.php?p=supra-resistance-supra) one and following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity) article.